# How to update collections and restore while doing mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

is there any way that i can update the collection and restore  the same from dump created by mongodump cmd . 
when we do mongorestore , it directly restores from the dump , but my requireemnet is to update some data in the dump and then restore .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not possible. If you could update dump, you must have possibility to update indexes too...

Comment: Thanks . is there any other approach/workaround that we can think of for doing this ?

Comment: If you mongoexport data to json, then you can of course edit it.. Before you mongoimport it back.